# hbase-spark load data raise NullPointerException Error (scala)

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hbase

I want to load data from HBase by Spark SQL, I use the `hbase-spark` [official example](https://hbase.apache.org/book.html#_sparksql_dataframes) and it raise `NullPointerException`

My `build.sbt` file is:

```
name := "proj_1"
version := "0.1"
scalaVersion := "2.11.12"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-mllib_2.11" % "2.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-streaming_2.11" % "2.3.1",
    "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.3.1",
    "org.elasticsearch" % "elasticsearch-hadoop" % "6.4.0",
    "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-core" % "2.6.0-mr1-cdh5.15.1",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-server" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-common" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "2.1.0",
    "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-spark" % "2.1.0-cdh6.x-SNAPSHOT"
)
resolvers += "Cloudera Repository" at "https://repository.cloudera.com/artifactory/cloudera-repos/"
resolvers += "clojars" at "https://clojars.org/repo"
resolvers += "conjars" at "http://conjars.org/repo"
resolvers += "Apache HBase" at "https://repository.apache.org/content/repositories/releases"
```

The wrong code is:

```
def withCatalog(cat: String): DataFrame = {
    sqlContext
        .read
        .options(Map(HBaseTableCatalog.tableCatalog->cat))
        .format("org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark")
        .option("zkUrl", "127.0.0.1:2181/chen_test")
        .load()
}
val df = withCatalog(catalog)
```

Exception info is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.HBaseRelation.<init> (DefaultSource.scala:139)
    at org.apache.hadoop.hbase.spark.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:340)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:227)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:164)
    at hbase_test$.withCatalog$1(hbase_test.scala:57)
    at hbase_test$.main(hbase_test.scala:59)
    at hbase_test.main(hbase_test.scala)
```

How do I fix it? Can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

Ran into this problem recently. Suggest you try this:

```
    import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
    val conf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
    conf.addResource(new Path("/path/to/hbase-site.xml"))
    new HBaseContext(sc, conf) // "sc" is the SparkContext you created earlier.
```

The last expression is introducing a *stable* value into the environment; found this quite accidentally by scanning *Hbase*'s codebase.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I finally use the [shc](https://github.com/hortonworks-spark/shc) package, it works for me~

Comment: Might work for now but if the development of hortonworks and hbase diverse at some point in time; would be a risky thing to introduce unless your system is already reliant on hortonworks stuff. Just my 2 cents.

Comment: Thanks, this helped !